# iPhone - Escape charecter issue in JSON parsing 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, escaping, json

I am using objective C JSON parsing library and facing some issue . My web service returns the JSON response . My Parser fails when there is an escape character in the response string . Below is the response I am receiving from the server .[image: JSON response from the server]

Now if you observer the line
"item_name"     : "Spend$10andget$24worthofdonutsfromJim\'sDonutShop" , there is an escape character **Jim\s Donut** . My Parser fails to parse this with the exception.

```
 -JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=8 \"Illegal escape sequence '0x27'\" UserInfo=0x79cc420 {NSLocalizedDescription=Illegal escape sequence '0x27'}",
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Object value expected for key: item_name\" UserInfo=0x79cc510 {NSUnderlyingError=0x79cc470 \"Illegal escape sequence '0x27'\", NSLocalizedDescription=Object value expected for key: item_name}",
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Object value expected for key: parameters\" UserInfo=0x79cc5c0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x79cc540 \"Object value expected for key: item_name\", NSLocalizedDescription=Object value expected for key: parameters}"
```

All I am using is **JSON.h**

```
NSDictionary * responseDic = [responseString JSONValue];
```

Somebody please help me !! Thank you !!

Comment: Is this a valid escape character for JSON? http://www.jsonlint.com/ says it's incorrect. Any chance on fixing the web-service you're fetching the data from? If not, then I guess you could try to preprocess the input string replacing all the `\'` with `'`.

Comment: @Alex - this should be an answer :)

Comment: @Alex S. ohh . . But my web service is actually pulling some html string from the database and printing it in the JSON form . I can pre-process the string and can replace the \' with ' , but do you have any idea like are there some other escape characters being used in HTMl which also I need to take care or something .. ?

Comment: To make string parsing bullet-proof (no warranties implied), look at the escape sequences that JSON supports (the ones listed on http://www.json.org/ in a column on the right, those seem to be correct). Then you can preprocess the string eliminating every escape-sequence which is not covered by JSON. But please remember that the bug is in the web-service, so the work should preferably be taken on the server side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The escape sequence `\'` is not valid JSON.  See [json.org](http://www.json.org/).

You should raise a bug with the maintainers of the web service.

As a work around, you might try replacing the sequence with a single `'` e.g.

```
NSString* hackedString = [originalString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\\'" withString: @"'"];
```

Comment: Yes I have to change the services . But I have written total 10 services , So I just modified the JSON library to do this preprocessing for me and its working fine :-) . .  Thank You !!