# iPhone- \ character issue in JSON Parsing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using objective C JSON parsing library. My web service returns the JSON response. My parser fails as there is an '\' character in the response string. The response string is like `":\/\/68.491.5.780\/iphoneapplication"` but I want to be like `"://68.491.5.780/"`.

My code is here:

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:
  @"http:// url address/Accountservice/Security/ValidateAccess?accesscode=abcd&type=0"];

NSData *postData = 
  [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

So how can I remove all back slash "\" in the response receive from web service?

Comment: duplicate of this:  
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014409/iphone-escape-charecter-issue-in-json-parsing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can replace \ with whitespace like:-

```
NSString *str =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@" hi \ hoowoer"];

str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\""
                                     withString:@""];
NSLog(@"==%@",str);
```

**OUTPUT**

hi hoowoer

Comment: I used NSURL instead of NSString, when I used the codeline I am getting error as no visible @interface for 'NSURL' declares the selector 'stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString.'

Comment: your nsurl is URLWithString.. ?

Comment: yes, I need to get url (String) as a response and need to access that url.

Comment: have you trying  NSString *s=[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];

Comment: Are you available in chat of stack overflow, I need help from you,

Comment: check this also :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018347/removing-unicode-and-backslash-escapes-from-nsstring-converted-from-nsdata

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24806/discussion-between-nitin-gohel-and-sudheer-chekuri)

Comment: this removes both \ and " from the string. What to do if only \ need to remove and " will not